# Error: cannot assign a value to final variable

Tags: java, android, button, final

I am facing the following issue with Android Studio

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final int numeroHomem = 0;
    final int numeroMulher = 0;
    final int numeroPessoas = 0;

    final TextView campoTexto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pessoas);
    final Button botaoHomem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.homem);
    final Button botaoMulher = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mulher);
    final Button botaoReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);

     botaoHomem.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            numeroHomem++;
            numeroPessoas++;
            String mensagem = Integer.toString(numeroPessoas);
            campoTexto.setText("Total: " + mensagem + " pessoas");
            botaoHomem.setText(Integer.toString(numeroHomem));
         }
     });
 } }
```

> error: cannot assign a value to final variable numeroHomem
>   error: cannot assign a value to final variable numeroPessoas

Comment: Its easy to understand the error. If you declare a variable s final and assign a value to it at the time of declaration, you cannot change that value.

Comment: For variables, `final` means it is not possible to assign another value for that variable...

Comment: `final` means "constant" in java

Comment: It's quite **obvious**... a `final` variable is no longer... variable. It becomes a **constant**. And constants are... constant. They can't be "varied".

Comment: final values cannot point to different object

Comment: `final` is not constant, just not assignable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you cannot change `final` variable after initialization

what you can do is declare your variable in your class instead of `onCreate()`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int numeroHomem = 0;
    int numeroMulher = 0;
    int numeroPessoas = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


      final TextView campoTexto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pessoas);
      final Button botaoHomem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.homem);
      final Button botaoMulher = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mulher);
      final Button botaoReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);

      botaoHomem.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                numeroHomem++;
                numeroPessoas++;
                String mensagem = Integer.toString(numeroPessoas);
                campoTexto.setText("Total: " + mensagem + " pessoas");
                botaoHomem.setText(Integer.toString(numeroHomem));
            }
          });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is correct, basically declare the variable "up-top" rather than inside the function so to speak

Answer (score 0):

If you declare `numeroHomem` and `numeroPessoas` as final variables then you cannot increase their values later using `numeroHomem++` and `numeroPessoas++`. Just remove the final keywords.

Comment: That wont' work, the compiler requires all the variables, used in lambdas, to be effectively final

Comment: If the compiler really requires that variables be immutable inside of lambdas, you'll have to refactor your code. `final` means `final`

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the value of final variable, simply remove final from you variable.

```java
int numeroHomem = 0;
int numeroMulher = 0;
int numeroPessoas = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

As your comment suggests, the message `the compiler requires all the variables, used in lambdas, to be effectively final` implies that you need to set your variable to instance properties, so the compiler will know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue of Android Studio or Android in general. Once you have declare an object as `final` you can't change it. Create, for example, an utility class, declare in that class the `numeroHomem` and `numeroPessoas` as `public static` and modify them in the `onClick` method.